# Setting Option explicit off has no effect

Tags: vb.net

I was fooling around with the Option settings in Visual Studio 2015 and I noticed an odd thing, after setting Option explicit to Off in three places I still get a error message saying "Declaration expected" if I try to use a variable without declaring it first.  I set it to off in the properties of the project, by going to Tools>options>Projects and Solutions> VB Defaults, and in the code.  Below is the code from a simple class I created just to test this.

```
Option Explicit Off
Public Class Class1
    Test = "1"
End Class
```

The read squiggle appears under the undeclared Test variable.  I have no intentions of turning Options explicit off in a real project but I wonder what the point is of having the option to do so if invoking it doesn't do anything.  I'd appreciate a response from anyone who could enlighten me.

Comment: This is a simple syntax error, do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: Try putting `Test = "1"` inside a method.  I think even with `Option Explicit` off, you still have to give class members types.  Also, you may still need to use `Dim`.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454552/what-do-option-strict-and-option-explicit-do). The answer marked **TL;DR** is pretty good which gives you an example.

Comment: Hello Chris, of course you are right the assignment had to be inside of a method.  Once I did that the error was resolved and no Dim was required.  Thanks for your response.